# lcov for flutter sees just part of files

Tags: flutter, dart, lcov

I try to use lcov for flutter project in Ubuntu 20.04.

Firstly i run `flutter test --coverage`, then `genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html`.

But finally only small part of files is mentioned in report. There are no entire subdirectory such as `logic`, `ui`, etc, where code is placed too. And even if directory is processed for example named `domain` it processed partially.

[image: Here is file tree of project]
[image: Repost contains only small part of files]

Comment: Read this https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-actually-get-test-coverage-for-your-flutter-applications-f881c0ae8155

Answer (score 0):

first, execute this command for create a coverage helper test archive, make sure the test folder is created

```
file=test/coverage_helper_test.dart
echo  "// Helper file to make coverage work for all dart files\n" > $file
echo "// ignore_for_file: unused_import" >> $file
```

then execute this command for create imports of all files of your project o package, replace {YourName} for your name project or package, if you need exclude more extension add '!' -name '*.freezed'

```
find lib '!' -name '*.md' '!' -name '*.g.dart' -name '*.dart' | cut -c4- | awk -v package=$1 '{printf "import '\''package:{YourName}%s%s'\'';\n", package,$1}' >> $file
echo "void main(){}" >> $file
```

then run flutter test --coverage